# Using delegates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, delegates

I know that this may be tagged as a repeat question, but the ones that exist have not helped me implement delegates in Swift with SwiftUI. My issue can be see in the code below. I have a View and VM, TodaysVM. In here, I do a network request, that downloads movie data from an API, and saves the data to CoreData. In order to show graphs, the HabitVM needs to fetch the data from CoreData, and then do some long processing on it.

For this, I was looking into a way for one class to send a message notification to another class. So I stumbled onto using delegates (not sure if this is correct?). But essentially the idea would be that the TodayVM refreshes its data (which the user can do a pull to refresh on this page), it also sends a message to HabitsVM to start processing (so the data can be done by the time the user navigates to this page. I am not sure if there is a better way to do this, and I was trying to stay away from a singleton approach, passing one class into class, or creating a new instance of one of the classes.

In the code below, I have the delegates set up but 'print("Data update required!")' is never executed. From my research I understand this to be because I never set a value to the delegate? So the delegate value is nil, and therefore the

```
        delegate?.requireUpdate(status: true)
```

Is never actually executed. Which makes sense, since delegate is an optional, but never assigned a value. So I was curious how I would assign it a value in SwiftUI? And if using delegates is even the best method to have to separate classes send updateRequired status updates.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


// protocol
protocol MovieNotifierDelagate: AnyObject {
    func requireUpdate(status: Bool)
}

struct HabitView {
    @StateObject var habitVM = HabitsVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}

struct TodaysView {
    @StateObject var todayVM = TodayVM()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi!")
    }
}

class HabitsVM: ObservableObject, MovieNotifierDelagate {
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func requireUpdate(status: Bool) {
        print("Data update required!")
        reprocessData()
    }
    
    func reprocessData() {
        print("Processing")
    }
}

class TodayVM: ObservableObject {
    
    weak var delegate: MovieNotifierDelagate?
    
    init() {
        //Does some network call and downloads data, and saves to CoreData
        sendUpdate(status: true)
    }
    
    func sendUpdate(status: Bool) {
        guard status else {
            print ("No update")
            return
        }
        delegate?.requireUpdate(status: true)
    }
}


// Controlling Page
struct HomeView: View {
    //Default the user to the today view 
    @State private var selection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            HabitView()
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "books.vertical")
                        Text("Habits")
                    }
                }
            TodaysView()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "backward.end.alt")
                        Text("Rewind")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added code for a home view, which has both Views nested in a TabView so I think that answers your question. 

As for the TodayVM instance, that is created with the
    @StateObject var todayVM = TodayVM()

that is creating an instance of the TodayVM Class, and calling it todayVM, to be referenced as the view model within the view

Comment: A delegation pattern isn't going to work, since you can't assign a reference to the `HabitsVM` to the delegate property. You would typically have a model object that is passed to both view models. The view models are responsible for interacting with the model and exposing properties to their views. You would construct the view models, passing the model to their initialiser and the pass the view models into the views rather than using `@StateObject` in the views directly.

Comment: ViewModels shouldn’t communicate with each other. Move the data down to a manager so they can both share the source.

Comment: You would only do the long processing in a StateObject if you want it to cancel when the View disappears (and .task is better for that nowadays anyway). That's unlikely so this processing needs to be moved out of the UI layer.